# Replicability of RandomVariate within a function?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, random, scoping

I have a rather basic question but can't figure out a foolproof answer. In the following code, I build a function which returns the mean difference between successive elements of a vector created from `j` random variates from an exponential distribution:

```
fun2[j_] := 
    Module[{x = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/25], j]}, 
    Mean[Table[Abs[x[[i + 1]] - x[[i]]], {i, Length[x] - 1}]]]
```

Will the use of the `x` call to `RandomVariate` create an immutable object, i.e. so that `x[[i + 1]]` and `x[[i]]` reference the same instance of the distribution?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Any reason you are avoiding `Mean[Abs@Differences[x]]`? That seems a lot simpler here. Not to mention, it will be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Notice that performing the computation outside of the `Module` produces the same result.

```
SeedRandom[1];
fun2[10]

(* 30.5828 *)

SeedRandom[1];
x = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/25], 10];
Mean[Abs[Differences[x]]]

(* 30.5828 *)
```

In order to get the undesired behavior you would use `SetDelayed` as such..

```
fun3[j_] := 
 Module[{x := RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/25], j]}, 
  Mean[Table[Abs[x[[i + 1]] - x[[i]]], {i, Length[x] - 1}]]]
```

This gives a totally different result.

```
SeedRandom[1];
fun3[10]

(* 34.018 *)
```